# Time-limited encryption

Tags: encryption

Is it possible to set up an encryption scheme where the decryption key can only be used up to a certain date? i.e. past the certain date the data can no longer be decrypted. We can assume there is a reliable/mutually-agreed upon time reference.

Comment: If you use [x509](https://www.shellhacks.com/openssl-check-ssl-certificate-expiration-date/) the expiration date should always be checked.

Comment: One could always change the time before decryption...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to *cryptographically* guarantee that a key will be useless after a certain period of time. The most you can do is digitally sign an expiration date, telling any potential decryption utilities to first verify the date before decryption. The utilities will then be in charge of either reporting the fact of the expiration, or refusing to perform any futher actions. As mentioned in a comment, the [x509](https://www.shellhacks.com/openssl-check-ssl-certificate-expiration-date/) format provides that ability, and compliant utilities will (or at least should) check the expiration date.

The reason for this is simple. If you have *C = Enc<sub>k</sub>(P)* and *P = Dec<sub>k</sub>(C)*, where *P* is plaintext, *C* is ciphertext, and *k* is a secret key, it is logically impossible for the passage of time to change the behavior of a functional algorithm such that *P ≠ Dec<sub>k</sub>(C)*. You can of course have both parties agree to "forget" either *k* or *C* via mutually-agreed upon policies as other answers have described in more detail, but no matter how much time elapses, given *C* and *k*, you can always calculate *P*.

Answer (score 3):

As long as someone has the key it can always be used for decryption. Even on solutions where it's agreed that a key should not be valid after it has been expired, it's possible to create a tool that omits these rules, or simply spoof the date for an existing tool.

The only way to make a key invalid would be destroying it: that's naturally not a function of the key itself but the tool storing it. The *Extended Triple Diffie-Hellman* [X3DH Key Agreement Protocol](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/) is one solution that relies on this by using layers of keys with different time frames and using the combination of these keys for the encryption. Once the one-time key has been destroyed, there's no way to decrypt the data, and the outer layers are protecting the exchange of the inner layer keys. Again, this relies on the trust that none of the clients won't store these keys. No guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

If both parties work together, you can do so by policy. You can setup a scheme where the decrypting party needs to request (part of) the key from the encrypting party using some secure scheme and the encrypting party deletes the key on the server side after the key expired.

Nothing will stop the decrypting party from just storing the received key. But when you for example doing it in an collaboration where both parties want the data to be gone after the key is unavailable, the decrypting party may be trusted not to store the key.

Comment: No matter how honest each party is, the _key_ can be used indefinitely.

Comment: I the key is never leaked and always destructed right after using them, it cannot be used afterwards to reconstruct the data. This of course assumes you both want to destruct it to hinder third parties from decrypting something later, i.e. by forcing one of the parties to hand out the key and you can trust each other to comply to the scheme.

Comment: I had a more literal interpretation of OP's question, i.e. asking whether or not, given `C = E[K](P)`, you can make it such that, after a certain period of time, `P ≠ D[K](C)`.

Comment: I absolutely agree there. And I would see a lot of possible flaws in the policy based approach due to human error and technical difficulties (i.e. secure deletion of the keys), but it is still the best I can imagine to tackle the problem.